# Reading date in dd/mm/yyy format from csv

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a csv file with a date column in format 'dd/mm/yyyy', e.g. (31/12/2019). When I read it into pandas dataframe, it gets turned into '2019-12-31'. I tried converting it back, but the format doesn't seem to change to what I want.

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['dates'] =pd.to_datetime(df["notification_date"], dayfirst=True)
df['dates'] = datetime.datetime(df['dates'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: This is pure representation. Your date object is stored as datetime and displayed by default like you see it.You can change the dateformat-representation. See dupe.

Comment: something like `df.style.format({"notification_date": lambda t: t.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")})` could work